# Status of Nordwestblock / Ancient Belgian hypothesis

Tags: historical-linguistics, indo-european, germanic-languages, history-of-linguistics, celtic

What is the status of the [Nordwestblock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordwestblock) or [Ancient Belgian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Belgian_language) hypothesis right now?

This hypothesis was proposed independently by two authors in the 1960ies (Kuhn and Gysseling) and is about an Indogermanic language that is neither Celtic nor Germanic because of preservation of the original *p. According to the hypothesis this language was spoken around 50BCE from Belgium eastward up to the rivers Weser and Aller.

Since this hypothesis is now over 50 years old, what is its status nowadays? Could it be hardened by new evidence (from incriptions or toponyms), is it disproved, or is it just ignored because no-one bothers with it any longer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the topic of substrates in Europe has fallen into lack of interest, since the deaths of a number of German scholars.
Conspicuously, the book by Fortson on IEan language and culture does not even spend a detailed word on this topic. The word "substrate" apparently occurs only twice in the whole book, just to mention they exist!
I'm afraid the topic is currently in neutral gear.